# Laravel query builder select group and sum data

Tags: laravel, eloquent

We have a model called MoneyHistory and it has [database structure of table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcOyJ.png) fileds such as debt_id repayment_id(nullable) and amount (which can be negative if debt or positive if repayment). My mission is to group them by date and sum debts and repayments separately. Appreciate all answers!

I have tried it with eloquent builder but results were not satisfying.So result should look like this [json format of result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkZG8.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**
: Check the below link to see how I was able to accomplish your requirements with
GPT : https://chat.openai.com/share/1e187107-ca68-4b97-b081-2fe10267c873

There are a few ways to do this. Let me give you two options. But even using a simple GPT prompt you can find the answer for this.

**Using raw queries**

```
$result = MoneyHistory::select(
    'date',
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN amount < 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_debts'),
    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN amount >= 0 THEN amount ELSE 0 END) AS total_repayments')
)
    ->groupBy('date')
    ->get()->mapWithKeys(function ($item) {
        return [
            $item->date => [
                'date' => $item->date,
                'debt_sum' => $item->total_debts,
                'repayment_sum' => $item->total_repayments,
            ],
        ];
    })->toArray();
```

**Using Eloquent functions**

```
$result = MoneyHistory::select('date', 'amount')
->get()
->groupBy('date')
->map(function ($group) {
    $debtSum = $group->where('amount', '<', 0)->sum('amount');
    $repaymentSum = $group->where('amount', '>=', 0)->sum('amount');

    return [
        'date' => $group->first()->date,
        'debt_sum' => $debtSum,
        'repayment_sum' => $repaymentSum,
    ];
});
```

Here is the output

[image: result]

Here is the db table used

[image: db table]

Comment: Huge thanks to you Nipun. Both methods worked finely and as intended.